# store a large,structured text in android app

Tags: android, xml, string, sqlite, text

What is the most appropriate way to store some structured texts?The texts will be a collection of "books".each book contains a collection of articles,and each article has a title and a body.

The ways i could think of are:

1. create a database using sqlite
2. write an xml file in assets
3. put them into res/value/string
4. use java string

which method is the best for my situation?is there a better way other than those ive listed above?

Thanks in advance.

=========================

edit: Yes,the data can be regarded as static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML, or any other format you prefer in `res/assets` is the preferred way, if your data is static (it won't change).

If you want to work with dynamic data gathered from a webapp for example, then you should use the built in SQLite database.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for persistent storage then I would suggest a small SQLite database. You could also store it in XML documents and then use a ContentProvider to abstract your access to the books, but then you would have to write the I/O and XML-parsing operations yourself.